# onclick the div show the same div under it. Again i click hide or remove the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Once I click on the `div(class="a")` I want to get the content inside of that `div` and show it under the same `div`.

Once again if I click the same `div` the content displayed under should not be shown.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="">
    Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh 
</div><br>
<div class="">
    Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh 
</div><br>
<div class="">
    Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh  Logesh 
</div>
```

I need the solution using jquery or js.

Answer (score 0):

Use after to insert the text after the div, use a class to check if the item is present if its present remove it

Try the following:

```
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('red');
  if ($(this).next().is('.isVisible')) {//test if the item is present 
    $(this).next().remove();//remove it 
  } else {
    $(this).after('<div class="isVisible">' + $(this).text() + '</div>');//add it 
  }
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/bq1hewvs/8/

Answer (score -2):

checkout this:

```js
    

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('div.one p').css("visibility", "hidden");
            $('div.two p').hide();
            $('div.one').click(function(){
                $('div.one p').css("visibility", "visible");

                $('div.two p').toggle();
            });


        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one" style="border:2px solid red; width:50% ;height:30%;" >
    <p>content</p>
</div>
<div class="two"><p>div two content</p></div>
```